# Can I use 1920x1200 with this dual setup?

Tags: display

I have a 20inch LCD 1680x1050.
I want to get a 28 inch LCD 1920x1200.
I have Nvidia 8800GT.

If I hook these up to dual monitors, can I get resolution of 1920x1200?

If I can't, HOW CAN I???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume Windows, as you didn't specify an OS. Operating systems can't change the limitation of the hardware though, at least not without causing damage.

Your video card should have dual output (DVI, usually). Hook up both monitors and in the display preferences, you'll want to 'Extend desktop to this display' and select one of the monitors as your 'main' display (probably the 28").

You should be able to select 1920x1200 for the 28" assuming that is the native resolution for that monitor. However this doesn't magically allow your 20" monitor to use this resolution, it is limited to its maximum native resolution of 1680x1050.

For example, I'm typing this on a 27" @ 1920x1200, and my laptop has a 1440x900 display, with some other windows open; I can't make the laptop display go any higher. Nor would I want to, 1920x1200 on a 15" screen would make my eyes bleed from the smallitude.

Answer (score 1):

If the 20 inch is an LCD, then no. Otherwise, yes.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: LCD resolutions are limited moreso than CRTs.

Answer (score 1):

John is correct, you can't run your 20" at 1920x1200, but you don't have to mirror the displays you know. They can be set to separate resolutions in a side-by-side configuration.

Comment: So my 28 inch CAN run 1920?

Comment: You should be able to run your 20" at 1680x1050 while simultaneously running your 28" at 1920x1200.

Comment: But in the end, it really does depend on the monitor and the graphics adapter you are using.